# TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

### src/models/index.js

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var module = require('../module');
var config = module.Config;
const db = {};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.data('database'), config.data('username'), config.data('password'), config.all_data());

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

db.Test = require('./test')(sequelize, Sequelize);

console.log(db) // is not {}

module.exports = db;
```

### src/app.js

```js
// db
var db = require('./models');
console.log(db) // db is {}
db.sequelize.sync();
```

> db.sequelize.sync();
> ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined

Why db value is empty?

Comment: Solved. module.exports = db; to exports.db = db;